# formulas for coefficients of $n$th roots of power series

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there formulas for the coefficients of $n$th roots of functions like $1+x$ (and ideally also more general polynomials) viewed inside some power series ring like $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[[x]]$?

Where can I find formulas for things like this?

References would be appreciated!

Comment: Use the (generalized) binomial theorem on $(1 + x)^{1/n}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah cool I guess I just needed to know what to google. Thanks!

If you wanna post it as an answer I can accept it.